# Converting C to MIPS assembly with pointer

Tags: pointers, mips

```
int x;
int *ptr;

x = 22;
ptr = &x;
*ptr = 100;
```

How can i convert this code to MIPS language?

Comment: Either you do it manually, or you let a C compiler do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to save the memory of `x` in a register so you can save another word at that address. Here is the solution:

```
.data
    x: .word 22        # int x = 22;

.text

main:
la $t0, x              # ptr = &x;
addi $t1, $zero, 100   # add the value 100 in another temporary register
sw $t1, 0($t0)         # *ptr = 100;

lw $t3, 0($t0)         #if you try to print now the value, you will see that
li $v0, 1              #prints "100"
move $a0, $t3
syscall
```